# Turku and Tampere in one day?

Tags: transportation, finland, day-trips

I am traveling to Finnland this week. Some options I have is to visit the cities of Turku and Tampere but I dont know how long should it take to visit them. Is it worth it to visit the cities in 2 days or it can be done in one day trip?

I dont mind how to move between the cities (train, bus or maybe with a renting car) and I will be staying in Helsinki at the night.

Comment: I spent a whole day in Turku and still couldn't cover everything and I doubt you can do both in a single day. But I was walking and not riding a tour bus. And considering you are travelling from Helsinki, I won't count on it.

Comment: A train is only 2 hours so it's technically possible. Whether or not it's worth it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: It's not opinion based to say thst, while technically possible, this is *highly* unlikely to be a good idea.  If you're starting and departing from Helsinki, you'll be spending a bare minimum of 6 hours just traveling between the three, which leaves barely any time to explore either city.